# Is "high school detective" a real-life thing in Japan?

Tags: culture, detective-conan

In the show *Detective Conan*, the main character starts as a "high school detective" who shrinks down to become a child. In the series, there are mentions of other high school detectives as well, such as  Heiji Hattori.

I can see how the pill explains how the character became a child, but can't understand how it is at all normal he started as a high schooler who was a famous detective. I never saw any explanation for how he became famous for solving crime before he shrunk. It would have made more sense to me if a world famous detective in his 50's became shrunk down as a child, not a world famous high schooler detective, as no high schooler would be allowed to help the police. My question, is "high school detective" a phenomenon/concept that already existed in Japanese culture before the series existed? In other words, are there actually real high school detectives? And would they actually become famous for solving cases?

Comment: See this Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Persona5/comments/a5596u/how_can_characters_like_akechi_and_naoto_be/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No. It is totally fictional.

Technically, no license is required to become a detective (探偵) in Japan, so it is possible for a teenager to become a detective. I doubt there are actually such young detectives, but even if there were, it is *very* unlikely that they collaborate with real police or any official governmental body.

Comment: For Detective Conan I guess not but what about like Light in DN? Afaik, Light's 'duties' aren't really the same level as Conan's. Is it realistic to think maybe teenagers could come on cases on a temporary or part-time basis ?

Comment: @BCLC It should be equally unlikely. Maybe just as unrealistic as a Harvard freshman participating in a major FBI investigation.

Comment: sundowner yeah I guess. what about as an asset?

Comment: @BCLC what do you mean by 'asset'?

Comment: sundowner, you know (gasai), like when eg the CIA temporarily recruit someone on a temporary mission so they can help spy for the CIA. say, the CIA finds out the vice president of a terrorist organisation committed a crime against the org president so they use the VP to get info on the pres or the org.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if Light were ever likely to help, it would be more because he is a son of police officer. In reality, police inspectors may well use private contacts in their investigation, but it is unlikely to be a formal employment (even temporary). So in case of Conan, the relationship of Megure and Kogoro should be possible to an extent.

Answer (score 1):

Its fictional, Shinichi/Heiji and other high school detectives are murder magnets, and automatically happen to come where cases happen. They solve it and get fame easily. In real life this Dosen't happen!